# socket.recv is empty but the result is showing in Maya

Tags: python, sockets, maya, recv

I am trying to get values for the rotation of joints in Maya into an external IDE. I have successfully been able to send commands and Maya responds properly but I am having trouble understanding how to receive the results back in the IDE.

I have tried using socket.recv and socket.recvmsg but got errors for both.

Code running in PyCharm

```
import socket
host = 'localhost'
port = 7720

code1 = ("servo_1 = [cmds.getAttr('joint2.rotateY')]\\n"
         "print servo_1")
try:
   # Connect to Maya Command Port
   maya = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   maya.connect( (host,port) )
   # Send Command Through Socket --> Can Only Send MEL Commands
   message = 'python("{}")'.format(code1)
   print message
   maya.send(message)
   reply = maya.recv(4096)
   print reply
except:
   raise Exception, 'Connection Failed To : %s:%s' % (host, port)

finally:
   #Close Socket Connection
   maya.close()
```

Code in Maya to open the commandPort

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
if not cmds.commandPort(':7720', q=True, echoOutput=True, noreturn=False):
    cmds.commandPort(name=':7720')
```

The expected output is [43.74] as is shown in Maya but the actual output in PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by setting up a client socket connection from Maya to PyCharm making a python socket server and setting up maya as the client and using the pickle module to send a list.

Python Server

```
import socket
import pickle

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(4096)
    if not data: break
    conn.send(data)
    data2 = pickle.loads(data)
    print 'servo_1 = %s' % (data2)
conn.close()
```

Maya Client

```
import socket, pickle
import maya.cmds as cmds

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

max = int(cmds.playbackOptions( q=True, aet=True))
servo_1 = [cmds.getAttr("joint2.rotateY")]

data_string = pickle.dumps(servo_1)
s.send(data_string)

data = s.recv(4096)
data_arr = pickle.loads(data)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

CommandPort is meant for sending commands rather than retrieving output, there's still a way to do it: the trick is you need to send each command and receive output separately: https://forums.cgsociety.org/t/telnet-or-socket-no-result-back-from-maya/1730817/2

But the smart way to do is using `maya.api.OpenMaya` `MCommandMessage` message callback to stream output that maya received; So basically, a server (editor) client (maya) to send command, and another client (editor) server to stream output. This is how plugin's like **MayaCharm** (for PyCharm) and **MayaSublime** (for Sublime) work, and this is what I ended up choosing after some research. See detail examples:
https://www.xingyulei.com/post/maya-commandport/
https://www.xingyulei.com/post/maya-streaming/